# how to give setonitemclick listener condition in listiew

Tags: android

I am fetching the menucode from mysql database to android. if i clicking on item in listview and codez=1 means it navigate to another page else go to another page

```
      JSONArray json = jArray.getJSONArray("mainmenu");

        final List<String> codez=new ArrayList<String>();
         for ( i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
                codez.add(e.getString("menucode"));



         }
       list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {   

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            System.out.println(codez);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(codez.equals("1"))
            {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FoodMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }else
            {

            }
        }
    });
```

it prints all codes but not navigate can u please tell me the solution for above code

Comment: Are there any errors in your logcat output? Is `FoodMenu` correctly declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: I declared android manifest.xml correctly. no item prints all values in logcat thats all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`codez` is a `List`, not a `String`. So when you try to compare it to `"1"`, the comparison will always fail. Did you mean to choose one of the entries in the list instead?

Comment: how can i compare .while clicking of listview depends up on code it navigate different page .please help me

Comment: Your list could contain any number of entries. How do you know which one to compare with?

Answer (score 0):

1. `codez` is an array, so you don't compare it to string, instead, use the [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method.
2. If you expects to have only one code, use a String variable, not a list.

Answer (score 0):

correct your code

```
 if(codez.contains("1"))
        {
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FoodMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }else
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use loop to get particular case like

```
`for(int i= 0;i<codez.length;i++){
   if(codez[i].equals("1")){
      Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FoodMenu.class);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
}`
```

Hope this will help you.